# DateTimePicker Time validation

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I am trying to validate the chosen date by user using `DateTimePicker` with current time so user cannot choose time less than the current time as shown below

```
if (DTP_StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you cannot choose time less than the current time",
                    "Message",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information,
                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                    MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
}
```

But it now shown so for testing purpose I tried to display message to see what the value of these to condition and found that `DateTime.Today.Date` value is `00:00:00`

```
MessageBox.Show(DTP_StartTime.Value.TimeOfDay +" <> "+ DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay);
```

Is that the correct way to validate the time?

Comment: That is what `Datetime` returns as per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_Today.) You can however use `DateTime.Now` to get your times.

Comment: What kind of application is this, Winforms, WPF? Both have built-in validation mechanisms.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Winforms

Comment: @sam you can use the Validating event of the control then. Both Windows Forms and WPF already have validation mechanisms, used to validate individual controls, display error messages, asterisks etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime.Today returns the current *date*. If you want the current time you should use `DateTime.Now`.

`DateTime` values can be compared directly, they don't have to be converted to strings.

As for *validation*, just don't allow the user to select a past timeby setting the [DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.minimumdatetime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) property to `DateTime.Now` before displaying the form, eg :

```
DTP_SessionDate.MinimumDateTime=DateTime.Now;
```

There's still a chance that a user can take too long to enter a time and enter a time a few seconds or minutes in the past. You can still cover this by setting the minimum 1-2 minutes in the future:

```
DTP_SessionDate.MinimumDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
```

In any case, you can validate the value in code with

```
if(DTP_SessionDate.Value < DateTime.Now)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you cannot choose time less than the current time",
                ...);
}
```

An even *better* option though would be to use the validation features of the stack you use. All of the .NET stacks, Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, provide input validation either through validators, validation properties or validation events

[User Input validation in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/user-input-validation-in-windows-forms) explains the mechanism available to validate input on the Windows Forms stack.

These events, combined with error providers are used to display the exclamation marks and error messages typically shown in data entry forms.

DateTimePicker has a [Validating event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=netframework-4.7.2) that can be used to validate user input and prevent the user from entering any values in the past. The example in the event's documentation could be adapted to this :

```
private void DTP_SessionDate_Validating(object sender, 
            System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(DTP_SessionDate.Value < DateTime.Now)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        DTP_SessionDate.Value=DateTime.Now;

        // Set the ErrorProvider error with the text to display. 
        this.errorProvider1.SetError(DTP_SessionDate, "you cannot choose time less than the current time");
     }
}

private void DTP_SessionDate_Validated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // If all conditions have been met, clear the ErrorProvider of errors.
   errorProvider1.SetError(DTP_SessionDate, "");
}
```

The article [How to: Display Error Icons for Form Validation with the Windows Forms ErrorProvider Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/display-error-icons-for-form-validation-with-wf-errorprovider) and the other articles in that section explain how that control works and how you can combine it with other controls

**Update**

If you want to only validate the *time*, you can use the `DateTime.TimeOfDay` property :

```
if(DTP_SessionDate.Value.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very very useful information that covers a lot of  think one question  as you mention I can set the `DateTimePicker.MinimumDateTime` property to `DateTime.Now` so user will not be able to choose time in past ... but I think this way will not allow me to give message to user with what he/she done am i right ?

Comment: thanks for this point too `User Input validation in Windows Forms` in another case can I use it to prevent user from entering numbers within `textbox`?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't work with the `Date`, as it represents only "DATE", not "TIME". The property You want to use is called `Now`, which includes also the time.

```
if(DTP_SessionDate.Value < DateTime.Now)
{  ... }
```

**Update**

As requsted, if You are working only with the Time of the day,You can refer to it like this:

```
if(DTP_SessionDate.Value.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay)
{  ... }
```

`DateTime.Today` doesn't hold information about time. Only date. `DateTime.Now` however includes information about time.

Comment: works fine but I set breakpoint at the debug and noticed that `DTP_SessionDate.Value.TimeOfDay` format hh:mm:ss while the `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` has same format but with milliseconds is that will make any problem ? why they are not at same format ?

Comment: @sam The actual format is the same. The difference is based on that there are not miliseconds on the `selected` value in the `DateTimePicker`, but in the `DateTime.Now`, You have also included exact ms moment (and also tick of processors etc..) There is no problem about the comparing the times.

Comment: It is about visual studio showing the value in some format, where the `ms` are not shown when its value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_Now) that is what DateTime returns.

You can however use `DateTime.Now` to get your date and time.

Comment: but my DateTimePicker  format is Time so it should contain time am I right ?